# How to find $s(\exp(d(x)))$ ~ $ x + 2 $?

Tags: calculus, limits, asymptotics, exponential-function, function-and-relation-composition

Let $x$ be a positive real.
I want to find a pair of analytic functions $s(x),d(x)$ such that $s(d(x)) = x$ and

$ s(\exp(d(x)))$ ~ $ x + 2 $

More presicely I Also want :

$$ \lim_{x \to \infty} s(\exp(d(x))) - x - 2 = 0$$

Polynomials seem to fail as do polynomials of exp or ln.

Maybe try Lambert-W ?

Or do I want THE impossible ?

Comment: Note that $\lim_n a_n-b_n = 0$ does not mean the same thing as $a_n\sim b_n$.

Comment: I want both , so i edited with also

Comment: Related: http://mathoverflow.net/questions/4347/ffx-expx-1-and-other-functions-just-in-the-middle-between-linear-and-exp

Comment: @Jack D'Aurizio Im intrested in dynamics and tetration and I welcome your link therefore. However it might be " in the middle , it cannot be very close to a real iteration of exp. In that sense I think the link is not related.

Comment: @mick: I do not think so. Here we have $d(x+2)=e^{d(x)}$ hence $d(x+1)$ is the "functional square root of the exponential function" applied to $d(x)$.

Comment: Although possibly related to tetration , not in the way the link shows.

Comment: Yes but that does not give us d(x). I see no easy - in paticular in the link - way to go from the half-iterate of exp to d(x).

Comment: Tommy suggests using Carleman matrices, but with doubt.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

We have:
$$ d(x+2)= e^{d(x)} \tag{1}$$
hence assuming $d(0)=1$ we have that $d$ grows pretty fast: $d(2)=e,d(4)=e^e,d(6)=e^{e^e}$.

Now it is time to look at Anix' answer to [this MO question](https://mathoverflow.net/questions/20688/whats-a-natural-candidate-for-an-analytic-function-that-interpolates-the-tower/43003#43003).

Comment: Your correct. IT is tetration. Tommy posted about the same time to tetration forum this fact. We had a bet where the answer would-be first.  Hard call :)

Comment: Multitasking is dangerous. Well Thats my excuse ;)